# SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, nio

Is there a way to have an NIO server accept a connection and then start writing?

If I use the key combination

```
SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT | SelectionKey.OP_READ
```

I get an `IllegalArgumentException`. I have a server which accepts an incoming connection and then immediately needs to write to that channel.  I can't seem to be able to do this.

Comment: @close-voter There is nothing 'too broad' about this question, unless you don't know anything about it. It has a short and sweet answer.

Comment: Surely you mean `SelectionKey.OP_WRITE` above?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the value specified doesn't make sense. You can't read from or write to a listening socket, and you can't accept from a non-listening socket.

In any case you can start writing to the accepted channel immediately, without OP_WRITE. That's only used when you have filled the socket send buffer.